# Is the first pair of images for Text Protection in Google's Material Design wrong?

Tags: google-material-design

Looking at the [Style > Imagery section](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration) of Google's material design spec, under the "Text protection" section, it looks to me like their first pair of sample images is wrong.

The "Do" example of an email app doesn't seem to have any text protection, whereas their "Don't" example looks much better to me. Is that example wrong, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it appears as though the left image has no discernible scrim (as you point out), I think the dichotomy they are attempting to illustrate is "Don't Obscure the Image."

From a legibility standpoint, the right one is slightly better, but I feel the example on the left is visually superior, mostly by virtue of being cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

No, and if you read the text under the screens you will see why it's right.

> **Do.** Dark scrims should ideally be between 20%-40% opacity depending on the content. Light scrims should ideally range from
> 40%-60% opacity depending on the content.
>
> **Don't.** Don't obscure imagery when you use a scrim.

As you can see, the second one is an example of doing this *too much*.